# Vagrant, Centos7, Nginx, Uwsgi, Django. SSH + Nginx Connection Reset then Connection Refused

Tags: django, nginx, ssh, vagrant, uwsgi

### Solution

Always make sure you reserve your IPs when using a Static IP

### Versions

```
VirtualBox Version: 6.0.0 ( I think )    
Vagrant Version: 2.2.3    
CentosBox: "centos/7"    
Nginx Version: 1.16.1   
uWSGI Version: 2.0.18   
Django Version: 2.2.1
```

### Background

I have two vagrant boxes running, a test and a production. The only difference is IP and core count. I've set up both so I can ssh directly into the boxes, instead of having to ssh into the host machine and then run 'vagrant ssh'

### General Issue

The production version will randomly boot me out of the ssh (Connection reset by IP port 22) and then i'll get Connection Refused. If I ssh into the Host machine and then 'vagrant ssh' I can still get in and everything seems to be fine, I can even still ping other computers on the network. But I can't access it from outside the host, this goes for the nginx server as well (IP refused to connect.) on chrome

The issue will occasionally fix itself in a couple minutes, but the majority of the time requires a 'vagrant destroy' and 'vagrant up --provision' / recreate the box. I also occasionally get booted out of the Host Machine and well as the test box, but both I can still access externally after (even the nginx server on test) I'm working over a VPN and I also occasionally get booted out of that as well, but i can reconnect when I notice

**VagrantFile**

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# Please don't change it unless you know what you're doing.
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "centos/7"
  config.vm.hostname = "DjangoProduction"
  # Disable automatic box update checking. If you disable this, then
  # boxes will only be checked for updates when the user runs
  # `vagrant box outdated`. This is not recommended.
  # config.vm.box_check_update = false

  # Create a public network, which generally matched to bridged network.
  # Bridged networks make the machine appear as another physical device on
  # your network.
  config.vm.network "public_network", ip: "IP"

  # Share an additional folder to the guest VM. The first argument is
  # the path on the host to the actual folder. The second argument is
  # the path on the guest to mount the folder. And the optional third
  # argument is a set of non-required options.
  config.vm.synced_folder "./", "D:/abcd", type: "sshfs", group:'vagrant', owner:'vagrant'

  # Provider-specific configuration so you can fine-tune various
  # backing providers for Vagrant. These expose provider-specific options.
  # Example for VirtualBox:
  #
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
    v.name = "DjangoProduction"

    # test has these two commented out
    v.memory = 6000
    v.cpus = 4
  end
  #
  # View the documentation for the provider you are using for more
  # information on available options.

  ## Keys
  ### For SSH directly into the Box
  # Work Laptop Key
  config.vm.provision "file", source: ".provision/keys/work.pub", destination: "~/.ssh/work.pub"
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "cat ~vagrant/.ssh/work.pub >> ~vagrant/.ssh/authorized_keys"
  # Personal Laptop Key
  config.vm.provision "file", source: ".provision/keys/msi.pub", destination: "~/.ssh/msi.pub"
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "cat ~vagrant/.ssh/msi.pub >> ~vagrant/.ssh/authorized_keys"
  ##

  required_plugins = %w( vagrant-sshfs )
  required_plugins.each do |plugin|
      exec "vagrant plugin install #{plugin};vagrant #{ARGV.join(" ")}" unless Vagrant.has_plugin? plugin || ARGV[0] == 'plugin'
  end

  # Enable provisioning with a shell script. Additional provisioners such as
  # Puppet, Chef, Ansible, Salt, and Docker are also available. Please see the
  # documentation for more information about their specific syntax and use.
  config.vm.provision :shell, path: ".provision/boot.sh"
end
```

**boot.sh**

```
# networking
sudo yum -y install net-tools

ifconfig eth1 IP netmask 255.255.252.0
route add -net 10.1.0.0 netmask 255.255.252.0 dev eth1
route add default gw 10.1.0.1

# I manually set the gateway so It can be accessed through VPN

## install, reqs + drop things to places - gonna leave all that out
```

### Error messages

#### Django

This issue starting popping up earlier this week with django sending me error emails saying. it's always random URLs there's no consistency

```
OperationalError at /
(2003, 'Can\'t connect to MySQL server on \'external-ip\' (110 "Connection timed out")')
```

I used to get this email once every other day and paid it no attention, but currently it's sending me at least 20 a day and the site is almost unusable- it's either really slow or I get chrome errors: 'ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT' or 'ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED' or 'ERR_CONNECTION_RESET' .. it will be fine for an hour and then everything hits the fan
I originally thought it was an issue with the db or uwsgi or django, but working with it yesterday I realized there was a correlation with the timed out and getting kicked out of ssh.

**Nginx Server Settings** ( I have't changed nginx.conf )

```
upstream django {
  server unix:///vagrant/abcd.sock;
}

server{
  listen  8080;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
server{
  charset utf-8;
  listen 443 ssl;

  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/nginx-selfsigned.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/nginx-selfsigned.key;

  location / {
    uwsgi_pass  django;
    include /vagrant/project/uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_read_timeout 3600;
    uwsgi_ignore_client_abort on;
  }

  location /static {
    alias /vagrant/static;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
  location = /50x.html {
    root /vagrant/templates/core;
  }
}
```

**UWSGI command used**

```
uwsgi --socket abcd.sock --module project.wsgi --chmod-socket=664 --master --processes 8 --threads 4 --buffer-size=65535 --lazy
```

#### Nginx Error Logs

Nothing.

#### Messages file

only shows the '(110 "Connection timed out")' dump when it happens

Answer (score 0):

Can you test the behaviour but commenting the line "config.vm.synced_folder..."?

Comment: I think i figured it out already. The IP wasn't reserved on the network and another device took it, so the two were conflicting. I appreciate the suggestion tho(: